# Android <include layout inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

I have CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollview. I am trying to include the layout inside a nestedScrollView however, that layout assumes it can overlap the collaping toolbar. I have searched all over and could not find any solution to this problem. I also tried including fragment directly instead of a layout. That failed too. I also tried including a simple TextView inside the NestedScrollView - it worked. So the problem is clearly in the include. Please help me solve it.

DOESN'T WORK

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <include layout="@layout/content_detail"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

DOES WORK

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, I am a working text"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Full Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jennyeckstein.udacitycoursepicker.DetailActivity"
    android:background="#d82a2a">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#292c65">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="50dp"
            android:background="#78df49">




            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:contentInsetStart="50dp"
                android:background="#2cb27c">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_course_image_appBarLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    tools:src="@drawable/course_test_image"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/scrim"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                >



            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



        <!--<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, I am a working text"/>-->

        <include layout="@layout/content_detail"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

[GitHub link to the project](https://github.com/jennyEckstein/UdacityCoursePicker)

Comment: Had you tried to nest the include inside a Layout? Simple LinearLayout might solve it...

Comment: @Dieglock no it does not help, I tried Linear, Relative and even Frame...non fix the problem

Comment: can you post your whole xml?

Comment: @vrundpurohit I added a full layout file

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this kind of layout and codes are automatically generated if you choose BasicActivity. 
[image]
You can set text (contents) in `/res/layout/content_detail` , not in MainActivity 's layout.

Comment: yeah, I know its gets generated automatically. Sorry I do not understand what you suggest for a solution. Can you please explain.